# Remove an attribute from configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product

An attribute has been added in configurable products and has been made a required attribute when it shouldn't be. How do you edit it so it isn't required for every product?

Comment: Do you want to remove attributes or edit to remove the required field?

Answer (score 0):

Admin Panel -> Stores -> Attributes -> Products

Find the one that is the problem and change if it is required